# JNI - native method with ByteBuffer parameter

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

I've got a method:

```
public native void doSomething(ByteBuffer in, ByteBuffer out);
```

Generated by javah C/C++ header of this method is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java__MyClass_doSomething (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject, jobject, jint, jint);
```

How can I get a data array from jobject (that is a ByteBuffer instance) ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you allocated the ByteBuffer using ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() 
you can use [GetDirectBufferAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress)

```
jbyte* bbuf_in;  jbyte* bbuf_out;

bbuf_in = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buf1);  
bbuf_out= (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buf2);
```

Comment: The return type of GetDirectBufferAddress is void*, you need to cast it to a jbyte*:
bbuf_in = (jbyte*)(env*)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buf1); //C
bbuf_in = (jbyte*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buf1); //c++

Comment: @Error454 This is C, you don't need to cast `void*`s

Comment: You do need to cast if you have -Wpedantic