# How to send Java ByteBuffer to C using JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native, bytebuffer

Firstly, I want to say that the old answers doesn't work (for example, GetDirectBufferAddress function in below answers want one parameter now) at the moment as here:

[JNI - native method with ByteBuffer parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673839/jni-native-method-with-bytebuffer-parameter)

and here,

[how to write and read from bytebuffer passing from java to jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386176/how-to-write-and-read-from-bytebuffer-passing-from-java-to-jni)

It would be better if someone helps..

So, I can't send correctly my ByteBuffer, which's some elements filled,  to C from Java using JNI and I can't return that ByteBuffer's elements again to C

**My native function decleration:**

```
public native int myfunc(ByteBuffer pkt);
```

**Allocation for it**

```
private ByteBuffer pkt = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
```

**I am calling it in this way:**

```
System.out.println(myfunc(pkt));  // Doesn't works, throws exception
pkt.position(0);
System.out.println(pkt.get()); // works, when I do comment line above .println
```

**And my C codes as below:**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_xxx_myfunc(JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject); // header


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_xxx_myfunc(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject pkt) // function
{
  jbyte *buff = (jbyte *) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(pkt);
  // buff[0] = 0; I've also tried in this way
  return buff[0];
  //return 1; if I return 1, it returns correctly
}
```

when I run the java program it throws exception. How can I return my filled ByteBuffer values from C?

**EDIT**

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x719c16b8, pid=1096, tid=1900
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Emax I am using different pc to coding but edited question as trace's start

Comment: Ok but where did you allocate `pkt` ? Your question is lack of [mcve]. By the way, all examples show that you **must** send `env` as first parameter `env->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buf)` Do you have warning when you compile ?

Comment: @Stargateur sorry I had forgotten, but I edited for allocation line now. And as I specified in the question I cannot enter two parameter for GetDirectBufferAddress function. And I am not sure what buf is. Isn't buf is my pkt parameter? And no, there is no warning. I think, if there would be a problem in my functions I couldn't return 1 value to Java or couldn't print ByteBuffer's first parameter

Comment: If you can survive with accessing values one by one, take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo040

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use `GetDirectBufferAddress()` you must guarantee that **pkt** is *direct* (you can check this with [isDirect()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#isDirect())). The easy way to obtain such object is `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`. Direct ByteBuffer can be created from C++, too.

The difference between direct and indirect ByteBuffer is clearly explained in the Java [oficial doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

**Update** I see your update. No, `ByteBuffer.allocate(1000)` does not produce a DirectByteBuffer.

As [@Tom Blodget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2226988/tom-blodget) correctly [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175310/how-to-send-java-bytebuffer-to-c-using-jni/47177553?noredirect=1#comment81332728_47177553), the JNI [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress) explicitly says that `GetDirectBufferAddress()` can return NULL. This works both ways: the call itself should not crash if **pkt** is an indirect ByteBuffer, but you must check the result even if you are sure that **pkt** is a DirectByteBuffer.

Comment: Doing the "C" thing of checking the result of `GetDirectBufferAddress()` for `NULL` (per the [documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress)) would cover more cases than `isDirect()`.

Comment: @TomBlodget the "C" thing would not be to check `NULL` or `isDirect()`, is the user function responsibility to give correct argument (ofc course function must explicitly ask this kind of argument in doc) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `GetDirectBufferAddress()` except on a direct byte buffer. You don't have a direct byte buffer.